# VR arcade game teaches teenagers to live on another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to recall the title of a young adult-targeted book. It was probably published by Scholastic, or at least sold through their take-home pamphlets, which means it was probably published before I started high school in 1996. It's about a group of teenagers who receive invitations to play a game at an invitation-only arcade. When they go there, they are put in an immersive VR game in which they must learn to survive on an alien planet. I believe the game ends and they wake up back in the real world after they fall asleep on the alien one. They are invited back the the game a couple times, and then it turns out…

> …they go to play the game again, but they are unable to exit it. Eventually they realize that they actually *are* on an alien planet now, and that the previous game-playing sessions were just training for the real thing. I believe the epilogue states that all of the players have coupled up and the females have become pregnant, and they are optimistic about populating the new planet.

I think it was told in the first-person perspective of a female player. I don't think there was a real protagonist or strong conflict; just the group of players learning how to survive in the game. One of the other players had a photographic memory and used it to map the planet's surface. I think the cover art featured of a girl wearing a VR headset over her eyes, with her hair being blown back and her mouth open in surprise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of [Invitation to the Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invitation_to_the_Game) by Monica Hughes.  It's about a group of recently graduated students who live in a dystopian world and gain purpose in their lives by playing The Game.

The plot matches what you describe.  [Here's a review](http://thebooksmugglers.com/2012/01/book-review-the-game-by-monica-hughes.html) with a cover matching your description.

Comment: That's it! Thanks.