# Children in simulation of planet survival realize they are in the real thing now

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a book where children are classified into groups before leaving school. (my memory is slightly hazy) For some reason a group of children are chosen to try out a simulator and they are taught to survive on another planet. Then at some point it is no longer a simulation and they are actually living on that planet. Some one becomes very sick and almost dies, that is when they realize they are no longer on Earth.

Answer (score 5):

*[The Game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1442409398)* (originally published as *Invitation To The Game*) by Monica Hughes as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82267/23243

> It's the year 2154. Lisse and her friends have been deemed unemployable in the eyes of society. Now they must scavenge the disintegrating city for food and shelter, just to make ends meet.
>
> But their dismal existence starts to look up when Lisse and her friends are invited to participate in The Game, an experience highly regarded in their society. The Game is a virtual reality experience where they are challenged to survive. But as they spend more time in The Game, the line between reality and fantasy starts to blur. What started as a simple exercise quickly becomes a test of endurance, trust, and their will to live.

Comment: Also potential duplicates of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45110/vr-arcade-game-teaches-teenagers-to-live-on-another-planet and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75824/23243 (first one accepted)