# Trying to find a book called The Game

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, robots

So I read this book about 4 years ago in my middle school English class and I haven't been able to find it since. It is titled The Game, but that's not its original title. I cannot remember the original title.

It takes place in a post apocalyptic world where robots have almost completely taken over (most of the jobs are taken by robots). Parents are not allowed to raise their children, and those children are sent off to a kind of boarding school. Once the kids get old enough they take a test and that test determines if they get a job or live on government welfare.

The book focuses on one group of kids and none of them get jobs when they graduate.  They get separated and they get put in the city. Once in the city the government supplies them with food and clothes and other than that they have to scavenge for everything else. Eventually the group of kids come back together and live together. They hear about this thing called "the game" that the government runs and you have to be invited to play.

Eventually the group gets invited to this game.  Once they arrive in the place they're put under a simulation of sorts and wake up in an area where they have to figure out how to work together and survive basically. This goes on for a while until those who run the game decide that they're ready.

Then the group goes under one last "simulation" and they end up at the same area they've been in for the past few months but this time they come to realize it is not a simulation. They are on a completely different planet and actually have to survive. They live and end up creating relationships and mating.

They then come across another group like them and then the groups come to determine that the government for which they lived created the game because the population was getting too large and there aren't enough jobs for everyone. That's how the book ends.

Comment: Any of these? https://www.commonsensemedia.org/lists/books-like-the-hunger-games

Comment: No it originally had the game in the title. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Egads..  Take a breath (and have a paragraph) occasionally!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45110/vr-arcade-game-teaches-teenagers-to-live-on-another-planet

Comment: so... you lost The Game?

Answer (score 24):

*[Invitation To The Game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671866923)* by Monica Hughes, which was later re-released as *[The Game](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1442409398)*.

> It's the year 2154. Lisse and her friends have been deemed unemployable in the eyes of society. Now they must scavenge the disintegrating city for food and shelter, just to make ends meet.
>
> But their dismal existence starts to look up when Lisse and her friends are invited to participate in The Game, an experience highly regarded in their society. The Game is a virtual reality experience where they are challenged to survive. But as they spend more time in The Game, the line between reality and fantasy starts to blur. What started as a simple exercise quickly becomes a test of endurance, trust, and their will to live.